# Primefaces 3.4 dataexporter does not export values p:cellEditor

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.4 and trying to export a data-table with in-cell editing. It doesn't seem to work.

I have done the following:

Modified `org.primefaces.component.export.Exporter` line 143 and added this:

```java
else if (component instanceof CellEditor) { // Handle in-cell editable datatables
    return exportValue(context, ((CellEditor) component).getFacet("output"));
}
```

This is causing an extra row on top as well as an extra column to the right of the actual cells with data. With Excel files it's OK since they are not "visible" but PDF looks bad.

1. Is there a way to make PF 3.4 support this without changing the source code?
2. If the answer to the above is negative, can I make the PDF get generated without the additional row/column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is there a way to make PF 3.4 support this without changing the source code?*

No. You've to provide your custom `Exporter` implementations/overrides. I've already reported this as [issue 4013](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4013) several months ago. It not only mentions `CellEditor`, but also `HtmlGraphicImage` (we are using images to show boolean states, whose `alt` we'd like to show in PDF/XML/XLS/CSV reports).

All you can do is to vote for it so that it'll hopefully get more attention, or by re-asking it on [PF forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/).

---

> *If the answer to the above is negative, can I make the PDF get generated without the additional row/column?*

You can hide a column from export by setting the `exportable="false"` attribute.

```html
<p:column exportable="false">
```

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer, that's great and removed the extra column but I dont know why I have an empty row when exporting using PDF on the top of the table.  Kerem's reply above suggests that headerText is not supported. Is the row caused by this?

Answer (score 3):

> *Is there a way to make PF 3.4 support this without changing the source code?*

Yes. There is a **workaround**

Make two copies of your column.
First one is for **users** and second one is for **dataExporter**.

By setting `exportable="false"` in first column, hide it from dataExporter.

By setting `style="display: none"` in second column, hide it from users.

By the way dataExporter does not support headerText so if you need your headerText exported you have to use old style `<f:facet name="header">`.

```html
<p:column headerText="CLOSE DATE" exportable="false">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.closedate}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <h:inputText value="#{sale.closedate}"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>

<p:column style="display: none">
    <f:facet name="header">
         CLOSE DATE
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{sale.closedate}"/>
</p:column>
```

But this **workaround** is **plain ugly** and makes your dataTable twice in size and **hard to render**.

As BalusC mentioned we need to rise awareness about this issue by voting or posting in their forum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don't consider this to be a good way of doing things due to the relatively large amount of work involved in maintaining double tables in every page I have. Not to mention the design-perspective that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I've found so far is to make your own class that extends Exporter and to override method `protected String exportValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)`. You should only add 
`else if (component instanceof CellEditor) { 
   return exportValue(context, ((CellEditor) component).getFacet("output")); 
}`

Answer (score 0):

the answer is... create a data table with cell editor....

and after create an other table with no cell editor but the same fields into a

the exporter should be reference to the second table, and it is! :D

greetings!